# Angular application lighthouse report showing high JavaScript execution time on polyfills.js

Tags: angular, performance, performance-testing, lighthouse, spartacus-storefront

I'm running lighthouse report on my angular app which also uses spartacus storefront, getting high execution time on pollyfills.js, I am seeing zone.js is the only import in the polyfills.ts file.

[polyfills.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydoKQ.png)

Lighthouse Report:

[LightHouse Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFFiO.png)

How do I reduce the script evaluation time and minimize thread work on this? any help would be appreciated, thanks.

I tried updating the zone.js version to latest version, but didn't reduce time.